# Не работает .withGenereteMiniDrawer() в MaterialDrawer

Tags: android

Опробовал библиотеку MaterialDrawer от mikepenz только версия библиотеки в зависимости везде разная:

Вот это стоит на github:

```
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.5@aar') {
transitive = true
}
```

(к тому же у меня не добавляется в зависимости)
Так же я замечал и 0.9.5 версию (в которой нет нескольких важных методов), и 2.8.1 версию(в которой все работает, но только не добавляется MiniDrawer).
Насколько я понял нужно добавить MiniDrawer в элемент DrawerBuilder но в 2.8.1 и 0.9.5 версии он отсутствует. Решения найти не смог, может быть есть другие версии. Подскажите кто в курсе.

Comment: Чтобы найти последнюю версию надо идти на страницу либы на `GitHub` и зайти в раздел `releases` - там и будет на самом верху номер последней версии

Comment: Последняя версия как раз 5.9.5 что я и указал в начале, но с ней проект не синхронизируется и выдает ошибку: Error(29, 13) failed to resolve:...